# asterisk - Вызов скрипта, при поднятии трубки

Tags: asterisk, sip

Есть Asterisk Now(Version 6.12.65-26) - os: Linux

Задача: после того, как оператор взял трубку, был вызов внешнего скрипта. Пробовал что-то делать в файле `extensions_custom.conf`. Ставил по разному.

Смог настроить только, что скрипт срабатывает при входящем вызове, но чтоб при поднятии трубки оператором нет.

Пробовал и через AGI и System и Macros.

Можете на примере показать, что нужно сделать?

в гугле обыскал все что мог(http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?p=136759), но толку никакого. Хотя бы укажите где копать.

Многие подсказывают, что можно настроить через AMI.
Просто дайте хотя бы 1 рабочий пример, я уже сам раскопаю.

Вот, до чего я дошел:

```
[from-internal-custom]
exten => _XXXX,1,Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},60,U(answer-script,${PARAM}))    
same => n,Hangup [answer-script] 
exten => s,1,AGI(answer.py,${ARG1}) 
same => n,Return
```

answer.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import os,sys 
import datetime 
ROOT_PATH = os.path.abspath(u'{0}'.format(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))) 
file_name = os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'answer.txt')
with open(file_name, 'a') as file_to_save: 
   save_string= u"{0:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}:{1}\n".format(datetime.datetime.now(), sys.argv) 
file_to_save.write(save_string)
```

Работает вызов - все ок(*есть моменты с определением номера(как я понимаю это зависит от провайдера и настройки астерикса*), но это сейчас вторично)

Теперь проблема в том, что после вызова скрипта, когда оператор переключает на нужного менеджера, скрипт вызывается повторно и больше ничего не работает ( - подозреваю, что из за этой строчки **Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},60,U**

Мне не нужно еще один вызов, нужно чтоб работало только на поднятии трубки на входящем звонке для оператора( после того как оператор переключает на менеджера, вызывать скрипт не нужно )

Answer (score 1):

По приведенной вами ссылке указано правильное направление. Смотрите в сторону параметров команд Dial и Queue.

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+11+Application_Dial

`M - Execute the specified macro for the called channel before connecting to the calling channel. Arguments can be specified to the Macro using ^ as a delimiter. 
U - Execute via Gosub the routine x for the called channel before connecting to the calling channel. Arguments can be specified to the Gosub using ^ as a delimiter.`

> Теперь проблема в том, что после вызова скрипта, когда оператор
>   переключает на нужного менеджера, скрипт вызывается повторно и больше
>   ничего не работает ( - подозреваю, что из за этой строчки
>   Dial(SIP/${EXTEN},60,U

Попробуйте создать для переводов отдельный контекст, где нет опции U в Dial и используйте для его [установки](https://serverfault.com/questions/266811/transfering-call-asterisk-to-different-context) переменную **__TRANSFER_CONTEXT**.

Либо нужно в исходном контексте/скрипте определять, что этот звонок является переводом и не подставлять U в Dial.

Comment: все настроил, но возникла новая ошибка - скрипт срабатывает и на переводе оператора на любого сотрудника (((((

Comment: Обновите первый пост и добавьте код, где вносились правки.

Comment: обновил - посмотрите пожалуйста